# How to hide empty UITablecells?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

How can i hide empty UITableCells? My Tablecell contains a background so i tried this line of code

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return view;
}
```

But it didn't work (because of my uitablecell background)

Background:

```
[tabelView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table.png"]]];
```

Comment: I don't understand why table cells would exist if they were empty.  When your data source is asked for the number of cells, why not just return the number of "non-empty" ones you need?

Comment: what do you mean by "hide"?  do you want gaps in your table (i.e. in the middle) or would only the last cells in a table (i.e. the bottom most cells) be empty?

Comment: I mean the separate line of the uitablecells how i can hide them

Comment: You want to hide tableview cells, but you have posted code for viewforfooterinsection. Can you please post your code in cellforrowinindexpath ? Also what you mean by empty ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the dummy separators, you have to set the table view separator style to none, like this:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Note that this would hide the separator between non-empty cells as well. If you want to show the line between those, you have to take care of that yourself e.g. by using a custom `UITableViewCell` with a 1px line at the top/bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide the footer or the cells in the section?

If you have multiple sections you can check in which section the delegate actually is.

```
If (section == 0) {
Return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Version in Swift 2.0**

If you want tableViewController shows only defined cells, you have to implement delegate method `tableView(tableView:, viewForFooterInSection section:) -> UIView?` with empty UIView with clear color background.

In that case if you defined method `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` to return 3 cells there will be ONLY 3 visible cells without separators or any background on another cells.

Here you have my example implementation of `viewForFooterInSection`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        return view
    }
```